# Version Upgrade of Spring to 2.7.10 breaking onErrorReturn method in Flux

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb, reactive-programming, flux

We are trying to update spring version from 2.7.1 to 2.7.10 which does not allow null in inErrorReturn method. Our previous code is below. com.azure.cosmos.models.FeedResponse constructor is not public so can not send an empty object. I am new to reactive programming can somebody please guide how to resolve this?

```
 private Flux<FeedResponse<T>> createFlux(
  String type, Flux<FeedResponse<T>> feedFlux, String customerQueryData) {
feedFlux =
    feedFlux
        .doOnError(
            CosmosException.class,
            (err) -> {
              log.error(
                  "Exception Occurred While Executing Query={} exception={} ", customerQueryData, err);
              this.cosmosMetricsLogger.registerCosmosError(
                  this.database, this.collection, type, err);
            })
        .onErrorReturn(null);

return feedFlux;
}
```

New implementation of onErrorReturn in Spring2.7.10

```
 public final Flux<T> onErrorComplete(Predicate<? super Throwable> predicate) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(predicate, "predicate must not be null");
    return onAssembly(new FluxOnErrorReturn<>(this, predicate, null));
}
```